# WCF WebMethod with a blocking call

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

I am relatively new to the WCF paradigm and have a simple task at hand .

I have a webmethod like this .

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetUser", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
User GetUserById(User user);
```

I have impled this method in the following manner

```
public GetUserById(User user)
{ 
     //abc 
     // a long running task 
     return user;
}
```

I have a task that I should execute upon a certain condition inside this method, the result of which has no consequence to the current request. Hence the user should wait for this long running task to complete for them to obtain the result .

What should I look into ? . Is the .net await / async model the correct way to implement this task ? . Before I researched I randomly attached the keyword async to the long running method and it didn't work .

```
public GetUserById(User user)
{ 
   //abc 
   // a long running task 
   doLongRun();
   return user;
}

async doLongRun()
{

}
```

So then I planned to properly study the await/async model , but wanted to know if i was heading in the proper direction here?

Thanks

Comment: is the user object changed in this LRP method ?

Comment: Frank. Nope. It is not. Its a trigger that i need. It doesnt affect the user object in any way.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Then why should the user wait for the result?

Comment: Exactly . This is the problem. The user should not wait for the result. This is what i asked . How should i extract this blocking call away .

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib So if the same object is returned then simply change the return type to `void` as it's useless and on the `Client` side call the `GetUserById(user)` asynchronously. It will send the user object and then you code will continue and simply don't care about any call back.

Comment: frank the method does change the user object , you asked if the LRP changes it or not.

Comment: The LRP doesn't change the object, but the method getuserbyid does modify it.

Comment: then your method does 2 distinct jobs. this mean they are 2 methods not 1. The part that change the user object value should be called normally and the LRP called asynchronously. Second Option is a secondary web service that is called by the main one asynchronously which is much cleaner as you keep your LRP in another location (not affecting process on the main service)

Comment: what does doLongRun do? Is it CPU bound or IO bound?

Comment: Ned it is CPU bound. Frank thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Where is this app hosted? IIS? Windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `async`because you are not waiting for the result. Your method is CPU bound you can push it to the background with `Task.Run` if you want to execute it on the thread pool or `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => /*..*/,  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` if you want a dedicated thread.

```
public GetUserById(User user)
{ 
   //abc 
   // a long running task 
   Task.Run(()=> doLongRun());
   return user;
}


public void doLongRun()
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Man this looks exactly what i was looking for. I will give this a run in a bit and come back and tick this answer.